# What are the hardware differences between the Xbox 360 slim and the Xbox 360 E?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

What are the hardware differences between the Xbox 360 slim and the Xbox 360 E?

Are there any significant improvements or benefits of the Xbox 360 E that one should consider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 360S(lim) and [360E](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Xbox+360+E+Teardown/15062/1) are fairly similar, with some slight differences:

- The S has 5 USB ports, where the E has 4.
- The S was the last model to feature the ["AV Connector"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_accessories#AV_Connectors_and_Cables).  The E drops this port in favor of a separate HDMI port and composite (ugh) out port.  Optical audio appears to be missing.
- The case design has been updated to match the design of the Xbox One.
- The hard drive is slightly easier to remove, although it is still only replaceable with official Microsoft replacements.

Notable elements kept constant:

- Price & configurations.  The E [was introduced](http://kotaku.com/meet-the-new-redesigned-xbox-360-same-price-as-the-old-512347803) at the same price as the S.
- Fans & optical drive design.  This means the E likely has the same noise profile as the S.
- Architecture.  It's the same chips, same amount of flash, RAM, etc.  Halo won't run any faster on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add insight into why the E might be cooler.

I don't have an S but about it feeling like a better build and the E having a thinner case, well that would in fact make huge differences in heat transfer. The better build probably insulates more than than the other. The reason this wouldn't make any difference on the noise levels would be because the fans are mounted right on the other side of a plastic grill. Both models use the same case fans now if the E was a cheaper build AND stayed cooler they should've invested in a couple pennies for a quieter fan.
That could've taken way too much away from the S though, who knows...

Answer (score -2):

Other than the above, the Xbox 360 E is meant to be cooler (temperature) and quieter, though no-one can notice the difference.

Answer (score -2):

I have the Slim and the E. They both make the same noise when running. The Slim feels like a better build. The E is a good looker, but has a cheap thin case. Other than that, they both work the same with any game. So, if you have a Slim and it's OK, keep it.