# What exactly is stored on the Xbox console, the hard drive, and Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, hard-drive

Please be patient with me. I am a Mom, not a gamer. We have an Xbox 360 S with 250 GB that we are having to exchange for a new one. I have several questions.

1. What is the difference between the 360 S and the 360 E (i believe stands for Elite)? 
   Would this be an "upgrade"?
2. What is stored on the console, the hard drive, and Xbox Live?
3. What needs to be done to save everything so that it can be transferred or re-downloaded to the new Xbox?
4. Is there anything that won't transfer/ be lost?

more info...

The disc drive is broken on our 360S so the store is exchanging the one we have for a new unit. I don't know if the 360 E is a newer/better model. I was just wondering if it was I was going to ask for the upgrade. But from what you're saying, I should stick with the 360S.. yes?

Comment: Just a question, why are you going to exchange for the new one? 
The Xbox 360 S is very identical to the new Xbox 360 E

Comment: I recommend against the exchange, it is really more of an _update_ than an _upgrade_. See details at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120383/what-are-the-hardware-differences-between-the-xbox-360-slim-and-the-xbox-360-e

Comment: power to the mom

Answer (score 12):

This [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120383/what-are-the-hardware-differences-between-the-xbox-360-slim-and-the-xbox-360-e) explains the differences, so I won't go into that here.

On your hard drive you have:

- game saves
- game updates
- system updates
- downloaded games/content/demos/apps
- profile information
- movies/music you've downloaded

Xbox Live has your official profile information, which will be downloaded if you switch systems.

Assuming you don't have any non-live accounts, you only need to transfer your save files, and any media.  The updates and downloads can be re-downloaded on your new system.  In setting it up, you'll be able to download any Xbox live profiles, and retain secured data associated with them (like online multiplayer stats and progress).

To back up the game saves, I recommend using the cloud storage feature.  Microsoft [provides instructions](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-saves-in-cloud/cloud-save-games).

> **Existing game saves:** If you have an existing saved game that you want to store in the cloud, you can move the saved game to the cloud.
>   Here’s how:
>
> 1. Sign into your Xbox LIVE profile.
> 2. Go to Settings, and then select System.
> 3. Select Storage.
> 4. Select the storage device that contains the saved game that you want to move to the cloud.
> 5. Select Games.
> 6. Select the game with your saved game.
> 7. Select your saved game.
> 8. Select Move.
> 9. Select Cloud Saved Games.

You may then download them using the same Xbox live account on a different system.